# kafka connect jdbc source setup is not reading data from db and so no data in kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, db2, apache-kafka-connect

we configured kafka connect jdbc to read data from db2 and publish to kafka topic and we are using one of the column of type timestamp as timestamp.column.name , but i see that kafka connect is not publishing any data to kafka topic , even their is no new data coming after the kafka connect setup done , their is huge data in DB2 , so atleast that it should publish to kaka topic , but that also not happening , below my connector source configuration

```
{
    "name": "next-error-msg",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "connection.url": "DB_DATA_SOURCE_URL",
        "connection.user": "DB_DATA_SOURCE_USERNAME",
        "connection.password": "DB_DATA_SOURCE_PASSWORD",
        "schema.pattern": "DB_DATA_SCHEMA_PATTERN",
        "mode": "timestamp",
        "query": "SELECT SEQ_I AS error_id, SEND_I AS scac , to_char(CREATE_TS,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF6') AS create_timestamp, CREATE_TS, MSG_T AS error_message FROM DB_ERROR_MEG",
        "timestamp.column.name": "CREATE_TS",
        "validate.non.null": false,
        "topic.prefix": "DB_ERROR_MSG_TOPIC_NAME"
    }
}
```

my doubts are why it is not reading the data , and it should read existing data already present in the DB , but that is not happening , is their something i need to configure or add extra ?

Comment: Dig deeper. Look in the connector diagnostics, enabling additional trace if necessary. Verify the SQL-query outside of kafka to validate it. Ask Db2 to show what SQL is coming from the kafka connector , with what result.  DEBUG.

Comment: Just a random guess as you haven't provided any logs or as such. You are saying that you already have "huge" data in your database. But you are starting connector with only one task ("tasks.max"). It is possible that one task is not able to handle load from returned result set or connection is timing out. Can you try increasing this to 3 or more, assuming you have those many partitions for that topic.